# Count duplicate orders as 1 if containe the specific criteria

Tags: excel-formula

what I want is the 1 to show on the UNPICKABLE

[image]

Comment: Enter `=IF(OR(COUNTIF($J$2:J2,J2)=1,B2="UNPICKABLE"),1,0)` in K2 and drag down.

Comment: @ouroboros1  thank you, is working, but now is adding 1 to UNPICKABLE and to Reservable, in the same order. But what I want is if the order has UNPICK* and Reser* to add the 1 to Unpick* and to Unsati* and 0 to the rest, can you help me with that?

Comment: `=IF(OR(AND(COUNTIF($J$2:J2,J2)=1,COUNTIFS($J$2:$J$100,J2,$B$2:$B$100,"UNPICKABLE")=0,COUNTIFS($J$2:$J$100,J2,$B$2:$B$100,"UNSATISFIABLE")=0),OR(B2="UNPICKABLE",B2="UNSATISFIABLE")),1,0)`. Change `100` to last row of data. 2 added conditions in `AND()` check if the ID has associated rows in B with "UNPICK/UNSATISFIABLE". If so, then "RESERVABLE" get `0`, else `1` if it's the first. Else, we check if B2 is "UNPICK/UNSATISFIABLE".